# Ant+ iphone adapter configure for any sensor

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am building an iPhone app for heart rate monitoring using ANT+ technology. [This is the site](http://www.thisisant.com/)

But the issue is ANT+ iPhone adapters are manufactured by a few separate companies and they don't allow every sensor to detect by that adapter. Here are a few adaptors [Garmin iPhone adapter](http://www.thisisant.com/directory/garmin-ant-adapter-for-iphone/), [Digifit iPhone adapter](http://www.thisisant.com/directory/connect/), [Wahoo iPhone Adapter](http://www.thisisant.com/directory/wahoo-key-for-iphone/)

Android devices don't have this issues because most of the new devices have inbuilt Ant+ adapter. So we can directly build apps for android. But for iOS we need to have a separate adapter like this to detect the sensor.

Wahoo giving developers to access their SDK but only for there devices. They don't allow us to access devices like heart rate monitor, Bike speed monitor .. etc except their devices.

So my question is there any open source SDK to access these devices or is there any universal adapter to detect this ANT+ sensors.

Hope some one will help me with this issue. Because i am currently able to work with the devices build by those companies but i cant get access to my own sensor which is in ANT+ format.

Comment: You may want to ask this question on the ANT forums [here](https://www.thisisant.com/forum). Are you saying that you created your own ANT+ sensor that is not communicating correctly with these adaptors?

Comment: It looks like you need to become a certified manufacturer in order to be able to provide your own adapter. You should have a look at Apple's MFI program: https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/